# Average of several Ruby arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have three Ruby arrays:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How can I take the average of all three numbers in position `0`, then position `1`, etc. and store them in a new array called 'Average'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [3, 4, 5, 6]

a.zip(b,c)
   # [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
.map {|array| array.reduce(:+) / array.size }
   # => [ 2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: This is nice. Be careful with zip if your arrays have different sizes, because it'll apply nil to the result and in this case, throw an exception

Comment: There are two things worth mentioning. First, you `[a,b,c].transpose` is a nice alternative for `a.zip(b,c)`. Second, you are dealing with integers in this example only and might get issues if division does not work without remainder. I'd go for `[a,b,c].transpose.map { |ary| ary.inject(:+) / ary.size }`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr = ([1, 2, 3, 4] + [3, 4, 5, 6] + [2, 3, 4, 5])
arr.inject(0.0) { |sum, el| sum + el } / arr.size
```

The concatenation could be done in several ways, depends on how you store your arrays.

As a syntactic sugar, you could do it like this too:

```
arr.inject(:+).to_f / arr.size
```